# Visualizing 3×3 spectrahedra

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to visualize the SDP cone over 3×3 matrices by plotting random 3D sections of it. Since each region is a system of inequality constraints, I'm using `RegionPlot`, but I think the plots would look better if they only showed the surface... what is a good way to achieve this?

```
spectro2 := (
   X = ( {
      {x1, x2, x3},
      {x2, x4, x5},
      {x3, x5, x6}
     } );
   vars = Union@Flatten@X;
   dvars = {x, y, z};
   m = Length@vars;
   n = Length@dvars;
   makeMat := X /. (Thread[vars -> #]) &;
   proj = makeMat /@ Orthogonalize@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m}];
   mat2 = 
    Total@MapThread[Times, {proj, dvars}, 1] + IdentityMatrix@Length@X;
   cons = And @@ (Thread[Eigenvalues[mat2] >= 0]);
   RegionPlot3D[cons, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, Mesh -> 5, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7], PlotPoints -> 5]
   );
Table[spectro2, {2}, {3}]
```

[image: spectrahedra]

Comment: Hmm. What's an SDP?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Probably ['semi-definite programming'](http://www.ifor.math.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/convexopt_ss11/Slides/Lecture_2)

Comment: @IstvánZachar [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) has a somewhat scant definition of spectrahedron. But, it may be enough to go be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the desire is to not have a surface appear when the region hits the boundary of the plot range, you could use something like:

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[Evaluate[cons], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, Mesh -> 5, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7], 
  PlotPoints -> 10], PlotRange -> 2.9]
```

to truncate the plot range to an area inside the boundary.

[image]

Comment: Ah, clipping the output range...yes, seems to do what I needed

Answer (score 2):

For plotting 3D surfaces, there's [ContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot3D.html). Here's an example from the documentation:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image: ContourPlot3D]

However, I can't modify your code because no matter what I change it breaks, so this is all I can give you here. Could you clean it up a bit and document what it's doing so we can actually play around with it?