# Functional style using lazy lists?

Tags: functional-style, lazy-computations, palindrome

Let's say I want to answer the question "what are the first 400 palindromic prime numbers?"

The first approach that comes to my mind from the set of languages that I know is to use some sort of lazy list materialization, a la [`IEnumerable` (and `yield`) in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929000719/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/03/14/digging-deeper-into-lazy-and-functional-c.aspx), [generators in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), or [`sequence` blocks in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx).

For example, in C#:

```
PrimesEnumerator().Where(n => n.ToString() == n.ToString().Reverse()).Take(400);
```

This would cause the PrimesGenerator to be pumped for primes long enough for the `Where()` clause to find enough numbers that meet the requirement for `Take()` to meet its quota.

The best I've come up with in Mathematica is something like:

```
i = 1; results = List[];
While[Length[results] != 400,
  If[IntegerDigits[Prime[i]] == Reverse[IntegerDigits[Prime[i]]],
    results = Append[results,Prime[i]]];
  i = i + 1]
```

It surprises me that I end up writing in such an imperative style in Mathematica. Am I missing something that would let me write this entirely functionally? Maybe even with lazy lists?

> **Update:** I took inspiration from [WReach's work of art answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/885/178), and made a package that took his ideas and expanded them into a broad, general solution for lazy data in Mathematica. I describe its usage in [an answer below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4093/178).

Comment: The code could be streamlined a bit: `For[i = 1; k = 1; results = {}, k <= 300, i++, If[IntegerDigits[Prime[i]] == Reverse[IntegerDigits[Prime[i]]], results = {results, Prime[i]}; k++]]; Flatten[results]`.

Comment: Seems like most solutions to a "find the first N" type of problem suffers from "guess how big of a `Range[]` you need to iterate through". It seems, at least in the general case, that there's no great way to avoid that. Maybe I need to write a "Lazy Generators" package for Mathematica.

Comment: Roman Maeder gave an implementation of lazy lists in one of his books (Mathematica Programmer). I used a technique described by @Sal, for a similar purposes: iterators - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596134/efficient-alternative-to-outer-on-sparse-arrays-in-mathematica/8609071#8609071, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs/569#569 (Module -> Advanced uses), more examples and links in my third post here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/5eff6213a0ab5f51.

Comment: @J.M., why `results = {results, Prime[i]}; Flatten[results]` instead of `results = Append[results,Prime[i]]`? I'm guessing it's to defer reallocation costs for `results`?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, that comment seems worthy of a credited answer. You'd certainly get an upvote from at least me.

Comment: The technique behind it was described in the aswer by @Sal already, so I did not think my additions would merit a separate answer. Thanks anyways, I am happy if that was helpful.

Comment: What is used in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/716/visualizing-3x3-spectrahedra) is very similar.  Just pointing to a practical use on this very site.

Comment: @sblom: it's a bit faster than `Append[]`/`AppendTo[]` when I checked. You might want to experiment on your setup to compare.

Comment: @sblom your package is an interesting work. Some usage examples would further increase its value in my opinion.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A "lazy list", "functional style" solution to this problem might look something like this:

```
sIntegers[] ~sMap~ Prime ~sFilter~ palindromicQ ~sTake~ 400 // sList
```

No such notation is built into Mathematica.  However, creating such notations is Mathematica's strong suit.  Let's do it.

First, we need to define the notion of a "stream".  Streams are inherently lazy, so let's use `HoldAll`:

```
SetAttributes[stream, {HoldAll}]
```

A stream can be empty:

```
sEmptyQ[stream[]] := True
```

... or it can be non-empty, having two elements:

```
sEmptyQ[stream[_, _]] = False;
```

The first element of the stream is called the "head":

```
sHead[stream[h_, _]] := h
```

The remaining elements of the stream are called the "tail":

```
sTail[stream[_, t_]] := t
```

Armed with these definitions, we can now express an infinite stream of integers thus:

```
sIntegers[n_:1] :=
  With[{nn = n+1}, stream[n, sIntegers[nn]]]

sIntegers[] // sEmptyQ                 (* False *)
sIntegers[] // sHead                   (* 1 *)
sIntegers[] // sTail // sHead          (* 2 *)
sIntegers[] // sTail // sTail // sHead (* 3 *)
```

Infinite streams are difficult to display in a notebook.  Let's introduce `sTake` which truncates a stream to a fixed length:

```
sTake[s_stream, 0] := stream[]
sTake[s_stream, n_] /; n > 0 :=
  With[{nn = n-1}, stream[sHead[s], sTake[sTail[s], nn]]]
```

Let's also introduce `sList`, which converts a (finite) stream into a list:

```
sList[s_stream] :=
  Module[{tag}
  , Reap[
      NestWhile[(Sow[sHead[#], tag]; sTail[#])&, s, !sEmptyQ[#]&]
    , tag
    ][[2]] /. {l_} :> l
  ]
```

Now we can inspect an integer stream directly:

```
sIntegers[] ~sTake~ 10 // sList
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

`sMap` applies a function to every element of a stream:

```
sMap[stream[], _] := stream[]
sMap[s_stream, fn_] := stream[fn[sHead[s]], sMap[sTail[s], fn]]

sIntegers[] ~sMap~ Prime ~sTake~ 10 // sList
(* {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29} *)
```

`sFilter` selects elements from a stream that satisfy a given filter predicate:

```
sFilter[s_, pred_] :=
  NestWhile[sTail, s, (!sEmptyQ[#] && !pred[sHead[#]])&] /.
    stream[h_, t_] :> stream[h, sFilter[t, pred]]

sIntegers[] ~sFilter~ OddQ ~sTake~ 15 // sList
(* {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29} *)
```

We now have almost all of the pieces in place to address the original problem.  All that is missing is a predicate that detects palindromic numbers:

```
palindromicQ[n_] := IntegerDigits[n] /. d_ :> d === Reverse[d]

palindromicQ[123] (* False *)
palindromicQ[121] (* True *)
```

Now, we can solve the problem:

```
sIntegers[] ~sMap~ Prime ~sFilter~ palindromicQ ~sTake~ 400 // sList

(* {2,3,5,7,11,101, ... ,3528253,3541453,3553553,3558553,3563653,3569653} *)
```

The stream facility we have defined here is very basic.  It lacks error checking, and further consideration should be given to optimization.  However, it demonstrates the power of Mathematica's symbolic programming paradigm.

The following listing gives the complete set of definitions:

```
ClearAll[stream]
SetAttributes[stream, {HoldAll, Protected}]

sEmptyError[] := (Message[stream::empty]; Abort[])
stream::empty = "Attempt to access beyond the end of a stream.";

ClearAll[sEmptyQ, sHead, sTail, sTake, sList, sMap, sFilter, sIntegers]

sEmptyQ[stream[]] := True
sEmptyQ[stream[_, _]] = False;

sHead[stream[]] := sEmptyError[]
sHead[stream[h_, _]] := h

sTail[stream[]] := sEmptyError[]
sTail[stream[_, t_]] := t

sTake[s_stream, 0] := stream[]
sTake[s_stream, n_] /; n > 0 :=
  With[{nn = n-1}, stream[sHead[s], sTake[sTail[s], nn]]]

sList[s_stream] :=
  Module[{tag}
  , Reap[
      NestWhile[(Sow[sHead[#], tag]; sTail[#])&, s, !sEmptyQ[#]&]
    , tag
    ][[2]] /. {l_} :> l
  ]

sMap[stream[], _] := stream[]
sMap[s_stream, fn_] := stream[fn[sHead[s]], sMap[sTail[s], fn]]

sFilter[s_, pred_] :=
  NestWhile[sTail, s, (!sEmptyQ[#] && !pred[sHead[#]])&] /.
    stream[h_, t_] :> stream[h, sFilter[t, pred]]

sIntegers[n_:1] :=
  With[{nn = n+1}, stream[n, sIntegers[nn]]]



palindromicQ[n_] := IntegerDigits[n] /. d_ :> d === Reverse[d]
```

Comment: I hoped you would answer. Your approach is, in fact, very similar to the approach taken by Roman Maeder in his implementation of lazy lists and streams in his "Mathematica programmer" book, except that he overloaded built-ins like `Map` etc with `UpValues`, while you created new heads. Very nice discussion and code - +1.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for the +1.  I was surprised that I got through writing this one without you getting there first :)  When I started out, I had [Common Lisp series](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node347.html#SECTION003400000000000000000) in mind.  But it ended up more like a toy Haskell :)

Comment: +1 ! Did you have this on the shelf or did you write it for this question?

Comment: @Spartacus I wrote it for the question, although it borrows concepts liberally from work I have done before in other languages.

Comment: Color me impressed.  I tried to implement something like that years ago and failed.  I might have been able to do it now but not that quickly or cleanly.

Comment: The syntax with sblom's package of WReach's solutions is Prime~Map~Lazy[Integers]~Select~palindromicQ~Take~30//List

Comment: I am total newbie in this area but I love to program with Pythonic list comprehensions. Is it easy to remix this style to create a style for functional Python programmers to get more involved in Mathematica? I moved my curiosity [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87025/building-pythonic-programming-style-to-mathematica-with-visually-accessible-list) and I would very thankful if you overviewed it.

Answer (score 43):

One way to get the lazy aspect is to use a closure, or the closest way for Mathematica to fake a closure.

This is the closures constructor:

```
makePalindromePrimeC[start_: 1] := Module[{p = Prime[start], r},
  ((r = NestWhile[NextPrime, p, 
       With[{d = IntegerDigits[#]}, d != Reverse[d]] &]); 
    p = NextPrime[r]; r) &]
```

This creates one:

```
palPrimeClosure = makePalindromePrimeC[]
```

Now you use it to generate some:

```
In[259]:= Table[palPrimeClosure[], {100}]

Out[259]= {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, \
383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, \
12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, \
16061, 16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, \
19991, 30103, 30203, 30403, 30703, 30803, 31013, 31513, 32323, 32423, \
33533, 34543, 34843, 35053, 35153, 35353, 35753, 36263, 36563, 37273, \
37573, 38083, 38183, 38783, 39293, 70207, 70507, 70607, 71317, 71917, \
72227, 72727, 73037, 73237, 73637, 74047, 74747, 75557, 76367, 76667, \
77377, 77477, 77977, 78487, 78787, 78887, 79397, 79697, 79997, 90709, \
91019, 93139, 93239, 93739, 94049}
```

Generate some more:

```
In[260]:= Table[palPrimeClosure[], {50}]

Out[260]= {94349, 94649, 94849, 94949, 95959, 96269, 96469, 96769, \
97379, 97579, 97879, 98389, 98689, 1003001, 1008001, 1022201, \
1028201, 1035301, 1043401, 1055501, 1062601, 1065601, 1074701, \
1082801, 1085801, 1092901, 1093901, 1114111, 1117111, 1120211, \
1123211, 1126211, 1129211, 1134311, 1145411, 1150511, 1153511, \
1160611, 1163611, 1175711, 1177711, 1178711, 1180811, 1183811, \
1186811, 1190911, 1193911, 1196911, 1201021, 1208021}
```

Now create an entirely independent instance that starts searching at the 500th prime:

```
In[261]:= palPrimeClosure500 = makePalindromePrimeC[500]

Out[261]= (r$10054 = 
   NestWhile[NextPrime, p$10054, 
    With[{d = IntegerDigits[#1]}, d != Reverse[d]] &]; 
  p$10054 = NextPrime[r$10054]; r$10054) &

In[262]:= Table[palPrimeClosure500[], {30}]

Out[262]= {10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, \
13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061, 16361, 16561, \
16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, 19991, 30103, 30203, \
30403, 30703}
```

Comment: It is indeed much faster then a blunt approach scanning all the numbers.

Comment: That's the closest thing I've seen so far. And I can even imagine getting rid of the NextPrime part by using another closure-as-a-generator for the prime numbers within the palindrome filter.

Comment: Wow! Nice. I should add that trick to my toolbox.

Comment: +1. I use similar techniques. I linked to some additional examples in the comment above.

Answer (score 31):

I took inspiration from [WReach's work of art answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/885/178), and made a package that took his ideas and expanded them into a broad, general solution for lazy data in Mathematica. You can find [my implemenation on github](https://github.com/sblom/mathematica-lazy).

To use the package to answer the original question from this post, you'd do something like:

```
palindromicQ[n_] := IntegerDigits[n] /. d_ :> d === Reverse[d]

Needs["Lazy`"]
Lazy[Primes] ~Select~ palindromicQ ~Take~ 400 // List
```

It can also do things like triangular numbers (from [Project Euler #12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12)):

```
divisorsLength[n_] := Apply[Times, #[[2]] + 1 & /@ FactorInteger[n]];

Needs["Lazy`"]
triangles = FoldList[Plus, 0, Lazy[Integers]];
triangles ~Select~ (divisorsLength[#] > 500 &) // First
```

Or some of the [even kookier Project Euler questions](http://projecteuler.net/problem=21):

```
Needs["Lazy`"]
Rest[Lazy[Integers]]~Take~ 9999  ~Select~
  ((Total@Most@Divisors@Total@Most@Divisors[#] === #) &) ~Select~
  ((Total@Most@Divisors[#] =!= #) &) // Total
```

Comment: I hadn't seen this post until today.  I haven't tested it yet but I commend the effort!

Comment: How about pumping with things like Subsets or Permutations?

Answer (score 22):

Not the "lazy" but **shortest**:

```
Select[ToString /@ Prime[Range[10^4]], # == StringReverse[#] &]
```

**Faster:**

```
Select[Prime[Range[10^4]], IntegerDigits[#] == Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]] &]
```

**Faster:**

```
Pick[#, (# == Reverse[#]) & /@ IntegerDigits /@ #, True] &@ Prime[Range[10^4]]
```

**Fastest:** (twice faster than the rest, but slower than "lazy")

```
Select[Pick[#,(#==Reverse[#])&/@ IntegerDigits/@ #, True]&@ Range[10^6], PrimeQ]
```

**Result:**

{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727,
757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421,
12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061,
16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, 19991,
30103, 30203, 30403, 30703, 30803, 31013, 31513, 32323, 32423, 33533, 
34543, 34843, 35053, 35153, 35353, 35753, 36263, 36563, 37273, 37573, 
38083, 38183, 38783, 39293, 70207, 70507, 70607, 71317, 71917, 72227, 
72727, 73037, 73237, 73637, 74047, 74747, 75557, 76367, 76667, 77377, 
77477, 77977, 78487, 78787, 78887, 79397, 79697, 79997, 90709, 91019, 
93139, 93239, 93739, 94049, 94349, 94649, 94849, 94949, 95959, 96269,
96469, 96769, 97379, 97579, 97879, 98389, 98689}

Comment: I really like that pipeline of functions you strung together in the `Pick[]` version.

Comment: @sblom Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Here is an attempt to do this in a more "functional" way, without thought of efficiency:

```
pQ = # === StringReverse@# & @ IntegerString@# &;

ppf[x_?PrimeQ] /; pQ[x] := x
ppf[x_] := ppf @ NextPrime @ x

$IterationLimit = 1*^6;

NestList[ppf[# + 1] &, 2, 399]
```

Comment: where's the infix?

Comment: @acl There is infix all over.  `=` `===` `:=` `+` `/;` all infix. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

A bit elaborate, but this works nicely for generating the first four hundred palindromic primes:

```
NestList[
  Function[p, NestWhile[NextPrime, p,
               (IntegerDigits[#] != Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]) &, {2, 1}]],
         2, 399]
```

---

An alternative route:

```
NestList[
  Function[p, FixedPoint[NextPrime, p,
               SameTest -> (IntegerDigits[#2] == Reverse[IntegerDigits[#2]] &)]],
         2, 399]
```

This alternate is a bit faster than the previous snippet on my system, but you should do your own tests.

Comment: I'll only note that the advantage of this approach is that it does not have to internally generate a list of length greater than 400. ;)

Comment: About twice as fast as [Artes' solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/840/52), before my suggestion, but slower than both of [Vitaliy's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/839/52).

Comment: @rcollyer: there's always the tradeoff between space and time, you know. :)

Comment: You just have to have to make sure your have the optimal Lorentz contraction.

Comment: @rcollyer Note that Vitaliy's both approaches are slower than mine if they have to return the first 400 palindromic primes. J.M's method as I pointed out is faster (since doesn't have to know in advance the length of range  of integers to select) but `NestWhile` makes resemblance of procedural approach. So one has to decide what he prefers

Comment: @Artes, I had missed the point about it being the first 400, and hadn't tested it out that far. But, for the shorter list (113 primes), Vitaliy's was faster. The addition of `Prime` supercharged your method and put it in the same league. But, required some knowledge of where to put the cutoff.

Comment: I definitely like that there's no "guess the `Range[]`" going on here. If only `NextPrime[]` could be generalized to other sequences. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if Vitaliy's approach is slower, but his method does't return exactly the first 400 palindromic primes.

Comment: @Artes to be clear: slower with a shorter list. Yours has a much slower growth curve and for 400 palindromic primes, yours beats him.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I had to make a correction, but I believe it is worthy if one makes extensively such seeking tasks. J.M.'s aproach and Mr.Spartacus' one are slower, although elegant.

Answer (score 13):

I recently published a lazy list package on GitHub, so I might as well show it off here:

https://github.com/ssmit1986/lazyLists

Installation instructions can be found on the GitHub landing page above (or in the README.md file).

My code overloads the normal list processing functions like `Map`, `MapIndexed`, `MapThread`, `FoldList`, `Pick`, `Cases`, and `Select`. `lazyRange[min, step]` is the basic constructor for generating infinite ranges of integers. `Take` will return a `lazyList` in which the first argument is the extracted elements and the second is the tail of the list (which can be used to continue extracting more elements). I implemented it using `ReplaceRepeated`, since that seemed to be the fastest option I could find.

Example:

```
<< lazyLists`;
Take[Select[Map[Prime, lazyRange[]], PalindromeQ], 400]

Out[138]= lazyList[{<<primes>>}, <<tail>>]
```

*Edit* 
I'm still updating this repository with new functionalities and I'm open to suggestions. See the README file on the landing page for the update history.

Comment: (+1) Please, describe how to install.

Comment: "Just download the repository (and unzip if necessary)." -- I did that. I was asking on behalf of the (GitHub) unwashed masses.

Comment: Ok, got it. The landing page on github should be fairly self-explanatory now, I hope :).

Comment: @AntonAntonov , nice tutorial here: [Lazy lists in Mathematica](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1467915) ;-)

Answer (score 9):

There are many possible ways. Here is one in a functional style:

```
PalindromicPrimeQ[k_Integer] := 
    IntegerDigits[k] == Reverse[IntegerDigits[k]] && PrimeQ[k]
Take[Select[Range[4 10^6], PalindromicPrimeQ], 400]
```

returns a list of length 400 like this:

```
{2,3,...101,131,...3558553, 3563653, 3569653}
```

Updating after rcollyer's suggestions I would rather follow this way :

```
PalindromicQ[k_Integer] := 
    IntegerDigits[k] == Reverse[IntegerDigits[k]]
Take[Select[Prime[Range[300000]], PalindromicQ], 400];
```

**Edit**

It is worty to point out that Spartacus' test `pQ` seems to be a bit faster than PalindromicQ:

```
pQ = # === StringReverse@# &@IntegerString@# &;
Take[Select[Prime[Range[300000]], pQ], 400]; // Timing
```

Its timing : `2.152` versus `2.465` in case of `PalindromicQ`

Comment: Using `Select[Range[10^5], PalindromicPrimeQ]` and dropping `Take` gives the same results as [Vitaliy's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/839/52), but about 10 times as slow. But, if you select from `Prime[Range[10^4]]` (with `Take` still dropped), you get something a little slower than his `Select` method.

Comment: From Spartacus's answer, there is the alternative test `IntegerString[k] === StringReverse[IntegerString[k]]`. I wonder which test is quicker...

Comment: I checked the both tests for my second approach and and Mr.Spartacus' test is faster, timings were respectively 2.153 to 2.48

Answer (score 6):

I like WReach's answer because it shows how to compose an expression that is similar to the example in the question.  I like Sal Mangano's answer because it is concise and shows how to make something that behaves like a C# enumerator.  I hope to provide a little of each.

```
Enumerator[state_:0, increment_:(# + 1 &)] := Module[
  {s = state},
  (s = increment[s]) &
];

Where[predicate_][enumerator_] := Function[
  NestWhile[enumerator, enumerator[], Not @* predicate]
];

TakeEnumerator[count_] := Table[#[], count] &;

PalindromicQ := PalindromeQ @* IntegerDigits;
```

Please note that Enumerator and Where both produce pure functions that behave like C# enumerators but TakeEnumerator does not.

---

With that the example in the question can be expressed as

```
Enumerator[0, NextPrime] // Where[PalindromicQ] // TakeEnumerator[400]
```

**Result:**

```
{2,3,...101,131,...3558553, 3563653, 3569653}
```

---

Like in Sal's answer, you can assign to something that behaves as an enumerator.

```
palindrome = Enumerator[0, NextPrime] // Where[PalindromicQ];
palindrome // TakeEnumerator[10]
```

**Result:**

```
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191}
```

And repeat for the next 10:

```
palindrome // TakeEnumerator[10]
```

**Result:**

```
{313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929}
```

---

And you can quickly compose enumerators:

```
Enumerator[] /* (#^2 &) // TakeEnumerator[10]
```

**Result:**

```
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}
```

or

```
Enumerator[] /* (#^2 &) /* Sqrt // TakeEnumerator[10]
```

**Result:**

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```