# Can I use Table without the appropriate bounds?

Tags: syntax

I'd like to use the `Table` command without defining `n`, so that I can have a list of `n` arguments.

It is possible for the `Sum` command, but I guess not for the `Table` command, or is it? Something like

```
n = 5; eSO = Table[e[i], {i, 1, n}]; ebar[1] = EBAU - Sum[ebar[i], {i, 2, n}]; 
a[1] = A - Sum[a[i], {i, 2, n}]; b[1] = B - Sum[b[i], {i, 2, n}];

Cost = Table[1/2/a[i]*(ebar[i] - e[i])^2 + b[i]*(Sum[e[i], {i, n}])^2 /2, {i, 1, n}];

FOC = Table[D[Sum[Cost[[i]], {i, n}] == 0, e[i]], {i, 1, n}];

solsSO = eSO /. Solve[FOC, eSO];

solsSO = Flatten[solsSO];

ESO = Simplify[Sum[solsSO[[i]], {i, n}]]
```

but a bit more complicated in the end.

Comment: If you want that your m is not fixed but variable you could try something like:
`wi=Table[Table[Sin[i],{i,1,m}],{m,1,10}]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Are you looking for this: `Table[w[i], {i, {1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 2, 11}}]`, i.e. calling `Table` with a list of predefined index values?

Comment: Id like a list with dimension n, so id get.

{w[1],w[2],...,w[n-1],w[n]}

Comment: You might like to have a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists), which demonstrates how to represent indeterminate-length (or infinite) lists in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thx but that seems a bit over my head.

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing this atm, but you might consider changing the title of your post to attract more attention. As I see it, the problem boils down to solving a system of equations with a indeterminate number of variables.

Comment: @sebhofer I probably stick to what you said about just checking my pen and paper results. To you last remark: It rather boils down to solving a system of equations where the number of equations is indeterminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible because it makes as much sense as wanting to have list of `n` elements with `n` being undefined. The most similar thing you can do is to have a symbolic representation of that, that evaluates to what you want when `n` gets a numeric value. For that, you can either define your own

```
symbolicTable[exp_, it:{_, __?NumericQ| _List}]:=Table[exp, it]
```

If you then use `symbolicTable` just like `Table`, it will only evaluate when the iterator bounds are numeric and remain unevaluated when they are not.

ooor, just turn off the warning message you get when you try to use `Table` with a non-numeric argument

```
Off[Table::iterb]
```

Comment: Thx for you reply, but does this really help me with my problem? Maybe, I dont really understand your proposal. I still wont be able to have a list with n arguments then, will I?

Comment: @Max: we might be more helpful if you tell us your **actual problem**, that is, the problem that requires this construction you speak of.

Comment: Its a rather simple optimization in economics. n would be the number of countries for which I have some cost function over which i minimize.
Therefore I d like to have a list for the n countries where each argument represents one country, then do the differentiation and solve it. (still haveing trouble using minimize or sth similar). 
I can understand if that doesnt work since the program probably needs appropiate bounds for the list and the differentiation.
if wi = Table[w[i], {i, 1, m}] is already not possible then the rest wont be either, i guess.

Comment: @MaxM So do you want to do an analytical or a numerical calculation?

Comment: Analytical. I ve done it with pen and paper, but would like to verify it and since i wanna do some further calculation with would be a bit messy it would be nice to have it in mathematica as well for numerical simulation.

Comment: @MaxM, I don't think `Table` can be used like that for analytical problems. You probably have to adapt your question giving more specifics of the problem at hand, to get real help

Comment: @MaxM I agree with Rojo, it would definitely help do see a few equations to illustrate the problem better. On a more general note: If you solved your problem by hand already, I would stick to checking the result numerically for a few cases and start using Mathematica from there.

Comment: I just copied and pasted it now, id love to be able to include it in a better way, but i just couldnt find out how. 

when u run the lines you will see that the solution does not depend on N. We call this the social planner solution. I dont know how much it would help to go into the problem?

It some quadratic cost function and a quadratic Damage function of the sum of emissions. e_i is supposed to be emissions and e_bar is Business as Usual emissions. the a_i and b_i are just to have heterogeneous countries

Comment: @MaxM: You can include code to the original post (just as you did) and you can format blocks of code by selecting it and hitting Ctrl+K. Also, you can remove unwanted comments by clicking on the small X that appears next to them when you move your mouse over.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thx.