# Create a matrix from the rows of another, and calculate the rank of the new matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This may be a very basic question, so apologies in advance, I'm a first-time Mathematica & StackExchange user!

I have a 7x3 matrix X with all rows being unique in a 2D-list format.

For example:

```
X={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,1,1},{1,1,1}}
```

I want to choose three of these rows from which to construct a new matrix called Y, then calculate the rank of Y using `MatrixRank`.

For example:
`Y={{1,0,0},{0,0,1},{1,0,1}}` OR `Y={{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,1}}` OR `Y = ...`

What I really want to do is create a loop that chooses a different set of three rows each time, and calculates the rank each time, until I find a set of three rows where the rank of my matrix Y is some arbitrary value z.

Finally, I want the loop to finish and tell me which rows were used to create Y that gave a rank of z. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach from what you asked, but still produces the wanted result. I won't use a loop, while I will look for all the possible combination "at the same time" (it's not always convenient to use loops in Mathematica).

```
X = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
```

Generate all possible subsets of 3 rows:

```
subs = Subsets[X, {3}];
```

define a z value (for example 2):

```
z = 2;
```

Find all the combinations of rows that give Rank = 2

```
Select[subs, MatrixRank[#] == z &]
```

> {{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
>      1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 
>      1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 
>      0}, {1, 1, 1}}}

If you want the list of the rank of each subset:

```
MatrixRank /@ subs
```

> {3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. However, I have another example where my matrix X is far larger (56x21), and I wish z to be 21. This approach causes an error as there is insufficient memory for Mathematica to create all the many thousands of subsets of size 21x21. Is there a way to work out the rank of each subset and then stop when you find one that is 21, or another workaround that will take less memory? Thank you!

Comment: You might need to manually write a table or for loop for that, or you might look into lazy lists: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/lazy-lists-of-tuples-and-subsets . I don't have time now for implementing this solution but I might try it at some point!

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`Minors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html) to get all square sub-matrices of desired dimensions:

```
minors = Join @@ Minors[X, 3, Identity];
mr2minors = Select[MatrixRank@# == 2 &]@minors;

Row[MatrixForm /@ mr2minors]
```

[image]

List all 3X3 minors and highlight the ones with rank 2:

```
Grid @ Partition[MatrixForm /@ minors /. 
   a : MatrixForm[Alternatives @@ mr2minors] :> Highlighted @ a, 7]
```

[image]

Comment: Similar to my comment above, this solution works really nicely. However, it runs into the same problems with memory when the matrix X, and the integer z get larger. Any ideas for a solution? Thanks again!