# Generating all $k$ combinations from $n$ objects

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have $n$ numbers $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, is there a very quick way of generating $k$-combinations using Mathematica?

Comment: Take a look at `Subsets`.

Comment: Note also that `Range[n]` = `{1, 2, ... , n}` is useful for generating the list of numbers in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answer below `n=3` and `k=2`

```
Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 2]
```

> [image: tuples]

Compare to `SubSets`

```
Subsets[{1, 2, 3}, 2]
```

> [image: subsets]

Edit: many thanks to @BobHanlon for suggesting:

```
Subsets[{1, 2, 3}, {2}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Should probably include `Subsets[{1, 2, 3}, {2}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Can these subsets be generated iteratively instead of all at once?

Comment: @licheng See e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/lazy-lists-of-tuples-and-subsets) for lazy generation of subsets