# Prime-palindromic number selected from a list

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, palindrome

I want to find all prime-palindromic numbers up to 5000. Prime-palindromic numbers are numbers that themselves and their reverse digits are both primes. For example, 31 is a prime-palindromic number because both 31 and 13 are prime. Here is my code, but it somehow does not work.

```
 Select[Range@5000, PrimeQ[Join[FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]], # ]] &]
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functional style using lazy lists?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists)

Comment: The link above has great answers for this exact problem.

Comment: @RunnyKine But it is way over complicated, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, look at the third answer with about 4 variations.

Comment: @RunnyKine Got it. But I still want my code to work with the help of others.

Comment: There is also a [Demonstration Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PalindromePrimes/) for this.

Comment: @RunnyKine And when you see the result generated by that 4 variations code, it does not include `941`, which is a prime-palindromic number. So, I am suspicious of the code.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks, but the result generated still does not include `941`.

Comment: The reason their answer does not include `941` is because `941` reversed is `149` and these are not the same (the meaning of Palindromic). So your approach is actually wrong.

Comment: `941` is not a palindrome.  Your definition differs from the previous question.

Comment: @RunnyKine I'm gonna attach the picture from my homeowork set.

Comment: Well, I guess you should go with that definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you code

```
Select[Range@5000,(PrimeQ[#]&&PrimeQ[FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]]])&]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I also have a question. In my code, I was trying to make two lists with `#` into a single list by `join`. And then, I will apply `PrimeQ`. Do you know why it won't work, or do you have a better way to make the two into a single list?

Comment: @Lawerance, `Join` needs `Lists` as inputs. So if you want to do it your way here is how: `Select[Range@5000, And @@ PrimeQ[Join[{FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]]}, {#}]] &]`

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks a lot! I think I need to rephrase my title. It is not about finding the prime numbers, but to join the list.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see where you went wrong:

- `Join[a,b]` is *not* `{a,b}`, you have to type `Join[{a},{b}]` if you want to use `Join` in this way.
- The second argument of `Select` is a criterion function, it needs to return either true or false. Your function returns a list of boolean values instead. You need to check if all values in the list are true, so you need to use `And`.

Improvements of style:

- Instead of `Join[{a},{b}]` you can simply write `{a,b}`.
- Prefix notation (`f@expr`) can make your code look simpler.

Code:

```
Select[Range@5000, And @@ PrimeQ@{FromDigits@Reverse@IntegerDigits@#, #} &]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now know where I got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html):

```
Reap[If[PrimeQ[FromDigits[Reverse@IntegerDigits[#]]], Sow[#]] & /@ 
Select[PrimeQ][Range[5000]]][[2, 1]]
```

Or more concisely as per comment by @bmf:

```
Reap[If[PrimeQ[IntegerReverse[#]], Sow[#]] & /@ Select[PrimeQ][Range[5000]]][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: it's a (+1) from me with a gentle suggestion. This is shorter `Reap[If[PrimeQ[IntegerReverse[#]], Sow[#]] & /@ Select[PrimeQ][Range[5000]]][[2, 1]]` in case you are interested :)

Comment: @bmf thank you and thank you more concise code

Comment: don't mention it. my pleasure. it's a really nice answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just rephrasing the accepted answer with the help of a function:

```
Clear[primePalindromicQ];
primePalindromicQ[n_ /; n ∈ PositiveIntegers] := 
 PrimeQ[n] && PrimeQ@FromDigits@Reverse@IntegerDigits@n
```

*Usage:*

```
Select[primePalindromicQ][Range[5000]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**About using `Scan` instead of `Map` when using `Reap` and `Sow` in @bmf's proposal**

Using `Map` when using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
(*My mate @bmf*)
Reap[If[PrimeQ[IntegerReverse[#]], Sow[#]] & /@ 
Select[PrimeQ][Range[5000]]][[2, 1]] // RepeatedTiming // First

(*0.00932226*)
```

Using`Scan` when using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
Reap[Scan[If[PrimeQ[IntegerReverse[#]], Sow[#]] &, 
Select[Range[5000], PrimeQ]]][[2, 1]] // RepeatedTiming // First

(*0.0087359*)
```

The times obtained above using `RepeatedTiming` for both `Map` and `Scan` are quite similar, indicating that the efficiency of both methods is comparable for this data size. It's important to note that the real advantage of using `Scan` instead of `Map` in this context is to avoid creating an unnecessary intermediate list, but the actual improvement in execution time may be minor.

That said, the choice to use `Scan` instead of `Map` in this case is not just about efficiency. It is also a design choice that reflects the intent of the code. By using `Scan`, we indicate that the list of results produced by applying the function doesn't matter and that only the side effect is of interest (in this case, the seeding process with `Sow`).

In practice, for problems of this size, the execution time difference between `Map` and `Scan` is smaller. However, as the problem scales or is integrated into more complex code, these design decisions can have more significant implications for both efficiency and readability.