# How can I create a set (list) provide a kind of rule/algorithm?

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, rule, sets

Example:

S = {r ∈ Q : r² < 2}

> Let S be the set of all rational numbers whose squares are less than
>   2. It follows that 1 ∈ S, 4/3 ∈ S, but 3/2 doesn't ∈ S because 9/4 ≥ 2.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe *Mathematica* has the ability to represent an infinite set in that fashion.  You may find this useful however: [(838)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/838).  Depending on what you are doing you may also be able to give the conditions to `Reduce` or `FindMinimum`, etc., if searching for a particular value or range of values.  Could you give some examples of what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm trying to represent an infinite set as you said. Later, I would create, say, two more sets with a diff rule and then use the usual union/intersection (set operations). Maybe I use, instead, a plain function (with conditionals, say, IF something...). Would be nice to be able to use the Union / Intersection commands indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ImplicitRegion` to define this type of set.

Define your set.

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[r \[Element] Rationals && r^2 < 2, {r}];
```

Check that this works correctly on some rational and some irrational points.

```
Element[#, \[ScriptCapitalR]] & /@ {{1}, {4/3}, {3/2}, {\[Pi]}, {E}}

(* {True, True, False, False, False} *)
```

Define a larger set.

```
\[ScriptCapitalS] = ImplicitRegion[r \[Element] Rationals && r^2 < 3^2, {r}];
```

Compute the difference between the above 2 sets -- this is an "annular" region.

```
\[ScriptCapitalS]minus\[ScriptCapitalR] = RegionDifference[\[ScriptCapitalS], \[ScriptCapitalR]];
```

Check that this works correctly on some rational and some irrational points.

```
Element[#, \[ScriptCapitalS]minus\[ScriptCapitalR]] & /@ {{1}, {4/3}, {3/2}, {\[Pi]}, {E}}

(* {False, False, True, False, False} *)
```