# recurrence equation, result members don't contain the number 5

Tags: list-manipulation, homework

print the first 5 members of the array a[n+1]=3*a[n]+7 **which don't contain the number 5**.

a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWGMw.jpg)=6.

so a[2]=3*6+7=25, but 25 has the number 5 so we go to a[3].

a[3]=25*3+7=82 <--- this is OK... and so on until we print 5 members.

[image]

these should be the printed members.

Comment: Are questions considered duplicates if the recurrence relation has [different coefficients](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83568/26956)?

Comment: Should be, I think. What's up with this trend of questions, anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recurrence equation can be solved analytically

```
Clear[a]

a[n_] = a[n] /.
  RSolve[
    {a[n + 1] == 3 a[n] + 7, a[1] == 6}
    , a[n], n][[1]]
```

> (1/6)*(-21 + 19*3^n)

Generate a sufficiently long starting list, `Select` numbers that do not contain the digit `5`, and `Take` the first five elements of the remaining list.

```
Take[
   Select[
    Table[{n, a[n]}, {n, 10}]
    , ! MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#[[2]]], 5] &]
   , 5] //
  Prepend[#, {"n", "a[n]"}] & //
 Grid
```

[image]

Comment: One could also use `DigitCount[#, 10, 5] == 0 &` as the selection function.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis I find a bit of a speed penalty with the `DigitCount` approach though: `MemberQ@IntegerDigits` seems roughly 10x faster. `MemberQ` may be smart enough to stop as soon as it can determine its own truth value (i.e. when it finds the first 5 in the `IntegerDigits` list), so it doesn't have to traverse the whole list every time. On the other hand, `DigitCount` has no choice but to look at the whole list of digits (i.e. it calls `Tally` on the `IntegerDigits` list). I wonder if that's really why...

Comment: @Marco, interesting; I haven't looked at the time difference. Sounds like a good question… :)

Answer (score 1):

```
fun[n_] := 
 Reap[NestList[Sow[3 # + 7, FreeQ[IntegerDigits[3 # + 7],5]] &, Sow[6, True], 
    n],True][[2, 1]]
```

This will produce the numbers that comply,e.g. `fun[10]`:

```
{6, 82, 766, 6922, 20773, 62326}
```

If the `n` is desired:

```
funq[n_] := 
 Reap[NestList[
    Sow[{#[[1]] + 1, 3 #[[2]] + 7},  FreeQ[IntegerDigits[3 #[[2]]+7],5]] &, 
    Sow[{1, 6}, True], n], True][[2, 1]]
```

e.g. `Grid[Prepend[funq[10], {"n", "a[n]"}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon...you are correct! I will correct if and when I get time...recovering from a life threatening GI bleed and a hematocrit of 0.25 have rattled me...

Comment: @BobHanlon have corrected for my own peace of mind

Comment: Take care of yourself and good luck with your health issues.