# How can a function without an operator form be used in postfix form?

Tags: evaluation

As an exercise, I was trying to convert the following Clojure code to Mathematica:

```
user=> (->> (range)
            (map #(* % %))
            (filter even?)
            (take 10)
            (reduce +))
1140
```

I got partway with this code in which I wanted to use the postfix version of the corresponding functions in order to have the same reading of the functions as with Clojure's threading operator:

```
Range@20-1 // Map[#*# &] // Select[EvenQ[#] &]
```

I was stuck with the `reduce` because in trying to apply the equivalent `Take` and `Fold` I found out there's no operator form of these functions and so I couldn't use them in postfix form. Is there some alternative way to get the same left-to-right sequence of functions as with Clojure?

For those not familiar with Clojure, here's a [brief explanation of the threading operator `->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E#example-542692c8c026201cdc326a52) where I obtained the sample above. You can also find help and examples for the other functions at that link. Note that other than `reduce` (`Fold` in Mathematica) and `filter` (`Select` in Mathematica), the other Clojure functions have the same name as their Mathematica equivalents.

The `#(* % %)` is a lambda function (pure function as Mathematica calls them) and is equivalent to `#*# &`.

Comment: You can use **any** function in postfix form if you just make a pure function out of it, as you seem to be comfortable doing, like `// Fold[Plus, #] &`

Answer (score 5):

Since any function in Mathematica can be used in postfix form by appending `&` to make it a pure function, the following code can be used:

```
In[39]:= 20 // Range[#]-1 & // Map[#*# &] // Select[EvenQ] // Take[#, 10] & // Fold[Plus, #] &

Out[39]= 1140
```

Alternatively, `Total` or `Apply[Plus]` could be used instead of `Fold[Plus, #] &`; `Fold` is just the closest analog to Clojure's `reduce`.

The above doesn't exactly mirror the Clojure code since the upper limit for the range has to be specified in the `Range` call as there is no zero argument variant of `Range` in Mathematica. In Clojure, `range` without an argument returns a lazy sequence of 0 up to infinity which is determined only when the final expression is evaluated.

To get the first 10 even squares, we need to start with at least double that number and subtract 1 in order to match the 0 starting point of the Clojure `range`.

Comment: Downvote for un-truth (*"...does not have an operator variant so that it can't be used in postfix form"*): `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Take[#, 3] &`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know; updated answer to take this into account.

Comment: Right,downvote reverted. Instead of folding plus you could just use Total.

Comment: Lazy lists are implementable in MMA, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/885/26956

Comment: FYI: `Select[EvenQ[#] &]` may be replaced with `Select[EvenQ]`