# How can I express chains of filters using recurrence relations?

Tags: signal-processing, difference-equations

Here's example of what I would typically do in Python to play around with system of custom filters:

```
import math

# returns a simple lowpass filter function, based on the specified parameters
def filterA(alpha, initial):
    def f(x):
        f.prev = x * (1.0 - alpha) + f.prev * alpha
        return f.prev
    f.prev = initial
    return f

# create some test signal
testSignal = [math.sin(0.25 * x) for x in range(20)]

# see the result of applying two of these filters, chained together, on the
# test signal
print(map(filterA(alpha=0.95, initial=7.5), map(filterA(alpha=0.99, initial=-1.5), testSignal)))
```

I would like to express something like this in Mathematica so that I can

- use `Manipulate` and `ListLinePlot` to gain intuition on the effect of tweaking filter parameters
- use `FullSimplify` (and other functions) to see if a chain of filters can be combined into a single filter, or perhaps simplify the math in other ways
- perform symbolic evaluation of passing various signals through the filter chain (e.g. how does the system respond to a unit impulse function)?

Could `RecurrenceTable` or `RecurrenceFilter` be helpful here? I've been trying to grok them for a few days now and can't figure out how to use them for something like this.

Does Mathematica have something like a closure, where each successive call to a function can update state?

Please note, the exponential moving average I implemented above was just an example – the filters I'm working with are typically more complex.

Comment: You'll find an example of how to implement closures [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/846/12).  While not being familiar with the topic, after looking at `RecurrenceFilter` it does look like the thing you could use here (for good performance).

Comment: Not entirely clear what is wanted; would be better if specific input AND desired outpur were provided. The above can be solved analytically by the way: `recur[alf_, init_] := 
 RSolveValue[{f[n + 1] == (1 - alf)*n + f[n]*alf, f[1] == init}, f[n],
   n]
recur[.95, 7.5]

-0.05 21.0526315789^(-1. n) (-400. 1.05263157895^(1. n) 19.^n + 
   400. 1.05263157895^(1. n) 20.^n - 157.894736842 20.^(1. n) - 
   20. 1.05263157895^(1. n) 20.^n n)` . More generally, `RecurenceXX` functions can be used regardless of whetehr an analytic solution can be found.

Comment: `RSolveValue` looks promising. Thanks! I'm not looking for a specific input/output solution. I suppose what I'm asking is "how do people experienced Mathematica users work with recurrence relations in the context of signal processing experimentation?"