# How to use the iterator in Mathematica

Tags: undocumented, data-structures

I find that *Mathematica* has the iterator data structure. We can build some iterators like this:

#### Constant iterator

```
GeneralUtilities`ConstantIterator[5]
```

[image]

#### Key value iterator

```
GeneralUtilities`KeyValueIterator[<|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>]
```

[image]

#### Range iterator

```
GeneralUtilities`RangeIterator[9]
```

[image]

We can find all iterator functions with

```
Names["GeneralUtilities`*Iterator*"]
```

But I don't know how to process the iterator, as *Mathematica* has no function like `next` on *Python*:

```python
>>> string='FhC'
>>> it=iter(string)
>>> next(it)
'F'
>>> next(it)
'h'
```

---

### Update

Michael E2's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135921/21532) clear this problem a lot,But I hope the `DelegateIterator`, `IteratorGraph`, `JoinMapIterator`, `SingletonIterator`, `StreamIterator`, `TerminatorIterator` and `ToIterator` can be discussed still.

Comment: Re update: Their code can be inspected and it's fairly easy to understand, since it's so short.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's seem this seven function little complicate.You mean you understand it all?

Comment: I have no need to understand it all, but I can read, if ever I need them. But it seems they are under development (see comments to my answer), so I probably won't base code on them at this point. At least not code that I expect to use more than once. (Stuff in ``GeneralUtilities` `` sometimes changes.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Such functions set up a one-time iterator, i.e. a `` GeneralUtilities`Iterator ``. Its functionality may be inspected with

```
? GeneralUtilities`Iterator
```

and so forth.  Except for a `ConstantIterator` which always returns the same value (forever), they go sequentially through values until they return `` GeneralUtilities`IteratorExhausted ``.

The main (if internal) utility is `` GeneralUtilities`PackageScope`PullIterator ``:

```
foo = GeneralUtilities`KeyValueIterator[<|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>];

GeneralUtilities`PackageScope`PullIterator@foo
GeneralUtilities`PackageScope`PullIterator@foo
GeneralUtilities`PackageScope`PullIterator@foo
GeneralUtilities`PackageScope`PullIterator@foo
(*
  a -> x
  b -> y
  c -> z
  IteratorExhausted
*)
```

One can see from inspection with `?...` that one can do such things as `Map`, `Scan`, `Fold`, `Read`, etc., over iterators:

```
foo = GeneralUtilities`KeyValueIterator[<|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>];
Map[f, foo]
(*  {f[a -> x], f[b -> y], f[c -> z]}  *)
```

`Normal` converts them to a list:

```
foo = GeneralUtilities`KeyValueIterator[<|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>];
Normal[foo]
(*  {a -> x, b -> y, c -> z}  *)
```

Other functionality can be inspected with `?`.

Comment: +1.  It would appear that in V11 `Map`, `Scan`, `Fold` and `Select` are all eager.  This limits the usefulness of iterators (e.g. `Map[10 #&, ConstantIterator[3]]` is a bad idea).  I guess we'll need to wait for Leonid's streams to hit prime time :)  Incidentally, `Read` is the analog of Python's _next_.

Comment: @WReach 
1. Does it matter for `Fold`?
2. I wish you had referenced your discussion at
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists

Comment: @Alan No, it does not matter for `Fold` (I was thinking `FoldList`).  I suppose `Scan` is arguable as well since it is executed for side-effects.  Neither would be a good idea on an infinite stream.

Comment: +1, good exposure of internal stuff :). There is a hope that at some point soon iterators will get a standardized treatment in WL.

Comment: @WReach Hopefully soon now. Have to say though, that LazyList / its iteration process is only coarse-grained lazy, and works in chunks, where operations within a single chunk are eager. This is done for performance, in the first place. The user can in principle control the chunk size, but setting it to 1 will lead to really large framework overhead.