# Append a list as a column in a dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have a `Dataset` and a `List`, called dataset and intervals, and I would like to append the list as a new column of the dataset. I have tried:

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"char" -> 1, "freq" -> 0.1|>,
   <|"char" -> 2, "freq" -> 0.2|>,
   <|"char" -> 3, "freq" -> 0.3|>,
   <|"char" -> 0, "freq" -> 0.4|>
   }]
```

[image: original_dataset]

```
intervals = {{0, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.7}, {0.7, 0.9}, {0.9, 1.}}
ds[All, <|#, "intervals" -> intervals|> &]
```

[image: result_dataset]

but this adds the whole list to every row, whereas I would like each item of the list to be added to a different row.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: @Kuba I have added the results of my trial. The expected result should be that every row of the dataset should contain only the corresponding interval.

Comment: I know that the problem is that in this line: `dataset[All, <|#, "intervals" -> intervals|> &]` I'm adding the whole list to the column at every row, I need to somehow do `intervals[i]`, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, I didn't quite understand that. I don't need to copy the dataset, I just need to append a list as a new column of the existing dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52667/discussion-between-damjandd-and-kuba).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way:

```
ds // Transpose // Append["intervals" -> intervals] // Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In *Mathematica* it is usually easier to operate on rows, which is what this solution demonstrates. I would have done the same if I was working with lists too. However, as other answers show there are dataset specific solutions that might work better.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Another way:

```
ds[MapThread[Append[#1, "intervals" -> #2] &, {#, intervals}] &]
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I love it, but I do not know why it works!

Answer (score 12):

Suppose your column is a list of [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) objects or a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html):

```
ds = Dataset[{
<|"char" -> 1, "freq" -> 0.1|>,
<|"char" -> 2, "freq" -> 0.2|>,
<|"char" -> 3, "freq" -> 0.3|>,
<|"char" -> 0, "freq" -> 0.4|>
}];

intervals = {{0, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.7}, {0.7, 0.9}, {0.9, 1.}};

assoc=<|"interval"->#|>& /@ intervals;
col = Dataset[assoc];
```

Then you can simply use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) to add a column:

```
Join[ds, assoc, 2]
Join[ds, col, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: your first example doesn't return a Dataset for me on v12.1, but rather just a list of associations (on which you can simply apply Dataset to get a dataset)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using `MapIndexed`:

```
ds[MapIndexed[<| #, "intervals" -> intervals[[#2[[1]]]]|> &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

---

**Streams**

In some other software environments, *streams* are often used to solve problems like this.  For lists, we can define a poor-man's version like this:

```
stream[list_List] := Module[{i = 1}, If[i > Length[list], Missing[], list[[i++]]] &]
```

Then we can write:

```
nextInterval = intervals // stream;

ds[All, <| #, "interval" -> nextInterval[] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Streams can greatly simplify merging operations.  Let's say we wanted to add each interval as two columns instead of one:

```
nextLimit = intervals // Flatten // stream;

ds[All, <| #, "lower" -> nextLimit[], "upper" -> nextLimit[] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Or perhaps we wanted to add columns from multiple sources:

```
nextInterval = intervals // stream;
nextCode = "ROYG" // Characters // stream;
nextColor = {Red, Orange, Yellow, Green} // stream;

ds[All, <| #, "interval"->nextInterval[], "code"->nextCode[], "color"->nextColor[] |>&]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**Coming Soon?**

Since at least version 10.4 of *Mathematica* there has been an undocumented set of [iterator functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135916/142).  Perhaps they will become documented some day?  Then we could officially write:

```
nextInterval = GeneralUtilities`ToIterator[intervals];

ds[All, <| #, "interval" -> Read[nextInterval] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Also in the *Coming Soon?* department, we have the [Streaming package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85336/142) of [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin).

Answer (score 2):

More easy way

```
ds[All, Append["intervals" -> # & /@ intervals]]
```

[image]

Comment: This code does not produce a correct result.