# Combine points in 3D space by ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a array and I want to plot it in 3d space by `ListPointPlot3D` function.

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}};
ListPointPlot3D[list]
```

The result is as following
[image]

But I want to the two points lines combined. 
[image]

If I plot in 2d space, it works well by `ListPlot`, but I don't know how to solve it in 3D space.

Answer (score 3):

Add the x and y coordinates:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 2,    2, 2, 2}};
list2 = Thread[{1, Range @ Length @ #, #}] & /@ list;
ListPointPlot3D[list2, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) to transform input data into lists of `{x,y,z}` triples:

```
list3 = MapIndexed[{1, #2[[2]], #} &, list, {2}];
list2 == list3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`Iterator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-use-the-iterator-in-mathematica) in the `` "GeneralUtilities`" `` package to advance through the colors:

```
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`";
cyclicListIterator[input_List] := 
 GeneralUtilities`NewIterator[cyclicListIterator,
  {i = 0, n = Length[input], list = input}, list[[Mod[++i, n, 1]]]]

colors = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
       Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ListPointPlot3D]) // 
    cyclicListIterator;
ListPointPlot3D[{#}, PlotStyle -> Read[colors]] & /@ list // Show
```

[image]

Note: The `Iterator[]` for the colors needs to be reset after each use. One could use `With[{colors = ...}, ListPointPlot3D...]`.

The same thing but with old-style `MapThread`:

```
colors = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
     Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ListPointPlot3D]);
MapThread[
  ListPointPlot3D[{#}, PlotStyle -> #2] &,
  {list, PadRight[colors, Length@list, colors]}
  ] // Show
(* same figure as immediately above *)
```