# How to iteratively build a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I have the following c++ code that I want to translate to Mathematica.

```
std::vector<int> squbes;
for (int p : primes) for (int q : primes) if (p != q){
    if (p*p*q*q*q > maxi) break;
    squbes.push_back(p*p*q*q*q);
}
```

As you can see I simply have a list of numbers that I want to iteratively append elements to.

The first thing I tried was the following functional approach.

```
sqube[{x_,y_}] := x*x*y*y*y
unequal[{x_, y_}] := x != y
smallenough[x_] := x <= maxi
pairs := Select[Tuples[primes, 2], unequal]
squbes := Select[Map[sqube, pairs], smallenough]
```

However this is way too slow because it misses the very important break condition in the loop in the c++ version.

Next I tried the most direct translation I could come up with.

```
sqube[{x_,y_}] := x*x*y*y*y
squbes := {}
For[i = 1, i <= Length[primes], i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[primes] && sqube[{primes[[i]], primes[[j]]}] <= maxi, j++, 
        AppendTo[squbes, sqube[{primes[[i]], primes[[j]]}]]]]
```

However for some reason this turned out to be really slow, even if `primes` has only $100$ elements it took more than a second. I suspect `AppendTo` creates a completely new list every time?

The final thing I tried was to use `ReplacePart`, but the attempt is not even worth showing. First problem is that you need to initialize `squbes` to be large enough, even though I have no good idea how large it will be. Second problem is that I see no reason to assume that `ReplacePart` will not create a completely new list every time.

Can you please help me simply create this list of squbes in a decent amount of time?

Comment: an aside: `N` is a reserved symbol. You should get an error message if you try to assign a value to it.

Comment: Fair point, I changed it to `maxi`.

Comment: what is the interesting range for `maxi`?

Comment: maxi is about $10^{12}$

Comment: @SmileyCraft Are you sure that you have enough memory/mass storage to store a list of $10^{12}$ 64-bit integers? Apart from that, look up `Table` in the documentation.

Comment: There are not even close to $10^{12}$ numbers of the form $p^2q^3$ below $10^{12}$

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It seems to me `Table` is used to create a list, not to append something to a list or to change the elements of a list, so I do not see how that helps me.

Comment: That's right. But he who appends things to a list in a long loop needs to have good reason for that, because it is allways a major hit to performance. _If_  you really require dynamic appending, then I would suggest to get to know to (i) `Association`, (ii) `Sow` and `Reap`, or (iii) ``Internal`Bag``. The latter is not documented, though, but you can find details about it on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me see if I get this right. So you have

```
max = 10^12
```

and you are iterating over the same list of primes with a nested loop. Your inner loop iterates over `q` and we should first calculate the largest prime we need in the list to ensure that we are able to hit `max`.

Your very first iteration, where `p=2` is critical because `p^2*q^3` will be the smallest. So how about we find out for which prime `q` we make it above the `max` mark? Just for clarity, I'm making the code a bit verbose

```
With[{p = 2},
 MinimalBy[Range[2000],
  Abs[p^2*Prime[#]^3 - max] &
  ]
 ]
(* {819} *)
```

This tells us that we are passing the `max` mark for the 820th prime

```
2^2*Prime[820]^3
(* 1000664355604 *)
```

For collecting the values, I suggest you use `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `AppendTo` as it is faster. For the iteration, there are many choices. Let me use a simple `Do` in this case

```
result = Reap[With[
  {
    primes = Prime[Range[820]]
  },
  Do[
    If[p =!= q && p^2*q^3 < max,
      Sow[p^2*q^3]
    ],
    {p, primes},
    {q, primes}
  ]
]][[2, 1]];
```

That last `[[2,1]]` looks a bit clumsy, but when you read how `Reap` works, you'll understand its meaning. I got about 21k results and they all have the required form

```
result[[500]] // FactorInteger
(* {{2, 2}, {3581, 3}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

The ``` GeneralUtilities`` ``` package contains [undocumented iterator functionality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135916/142) that resembles the generator-based iterators from C++.  Perhaps these will make it into the core language some day.  Until then, the following iterator-based answer is mainly out of academic interest rather than a practical recommendation...

We start by defining `sqube` as in the question:

```
sqube[{x_,y_}] := x*x*y*y*y
```

We then define an iterator over all the primes (`RangeIterator` does not support `Infinity` so we use a googol instead):

```
primes[] := RangeIterator[1*^100] // MapIterator[Prime]
```

So then:

```
primes[] // TakeIterator[10] // Normal

(* {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29} *)
```

We will also define a useful helper iterator (which really ought to be built-in):

```
takeWhileIterator[crit_] := MapIterator[If[crit[#], #, IteratorExhausted]&]
```

Armed with these definitions, we can define our results:

```
results[maxi_] :=
  (* for (int p : primes) *)
  primes[] //
  (* not present in the C++, removes the need to know in advance how many primes *)
  takeWhileIterator[sqube[{2, #}] <= maxi &] //
  (* for (int q : primes) *)
  JoinMapIterator[
     ( primes[] //
       (* if (p != q) *)
       SelectIterator[Curry[#2 != # &][#]] //
       (* compute p*p*q*q*q *)
       MapIterator[Curry[sqube[{#2, #}]&][#]] //
       (* if (p*p*q*q*q > maxi) break *)
       takeWhileIterator[# <= maxi &]
     ) &
  ]
```

So then:

```
results[500] // Normal
(* {108, 500, 72, 200} *)

results[5000] // Normal
(* {108, 500, 1372, 72, 1125, 3087, 200, 675, 392, 1323} *)

results[10^12] // Normal // Short
(* { 108, 500, 1372, 5324, 8788, 19652, 27436
   , <<20952>>
   , 52810620731, 87171249997, 194935071113
   , 272147293459, 482754937967, 967692132989
   }
*)

% // Last // FactorInteger
(* {{29, 3}, {6299, 2}} *)
```