# Which operation combines {f,g,h,...} and y[u,v,w,...] to get y[f[u],g[v],h[w],...]?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a list of functions

```
myFuncs = {f,g,h}
```

which I'd like to map over an expression

```
expr = y[u,v,w]
```

to obtain `y[f[u],g[v],h[w]]`.  Which function(s) accomplishes this task?  The function is a combination of `Inner` and `Map`.

```
innerMap[myFuncs, expr] := (* ?? *)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[myFuncs[[#2[[1]]]][#] &, expr]
```

or

```
MapIndexed[Extract[myFuncs, #2][#] &, expr]
```

or

```
ReplacePart[expr, i_ :> myFuncs[[i]]@expr[[i]]]
```

or

```
expr // Query[Thread[Range@Length@myFuncs -> myFuncs]]
```

or

```
Head[expr] @@ Array[myFuncs[[#]]@expr[[#]] &, Length@expr]
```

or

```
Head[expr] @@ Construct @@@ Transpose @ {myFuncs, List @@ expr}
```

Answer (score 13):

Using `Mapthread`

```
innerMap[funcs_, expr_] := Head[expr] @@ MapThread[#1[#2] &, {funcs, List @@ expr}]
innerMap[myFuncs, expr]
```

> y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]

Comment: Instead of `#1[#2]&` you can also use `Construct` (introduced in 11.3)

Answer (score 11):

```
Inner[# @ #2 &, #, {##} & @@ #2, #2[[0]]] &[myFuncs, expr]
```

> y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]

or

```
Inner[Construct, #, List @@ #2, Head @#2] &[myFuncs, expr]
```

> y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]

Also

```
Construct @@@ Thread[{#2[[0]] @@ #, #2}, #2[[0]]] &[myFuncs, expr]
```

> y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]

and

```
Operate[Apply[#]@*(Compose @@@ Thread @{myFuncs, {##}} &) &, expr]
```

> y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this counts as a separate case *per se*, so here it goes:

```
threadOver[f_List, h_[x__]] := Inner[Construct, f, {x}, h]
```

As an example, evaluate `threadOver[myFuncs, expr]` to obtain:

> ```
> y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]
> ```

A more complicated instance of my `threadOver` function making use of [*ListCorrelate*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) could be the following:

```
threadOver[f_List, h_[x__]] := ListCorrelate[f, {x}, {1, -1}, 0, Construct, h] // First
```

#### Notes*:

The first version of `threadOver` (the one using `Inner`) seems  to be, for the most part, contained in the example provided at the '**Applications**' section for `Construct` at the [*Documentation Center*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Construct.html)

(*happy new year!*)

Answer (score 5):

It's funny how convoluted all of these answers need to be.  Here's another convoluted one. It's clunky because it does extra operations and then removes these extra pieces.

```
innerMap[fs_, expr_] := Through@*fs /@ expr // MapIndexed[#1[[First@#2]] &]
innerMap[{f, g, h}, y[u, v, w]]
(* y[f[u], g[v], h[w]] *)
```

(The function `MapIndexed[#1[[First@#2]] &]` was the best way I could come up with implementing `Diagonal` for arbitrary head expressions.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to modify `expr` in place, this would do the trick:

```
expr[[1;;-1]] = MapThread[Construct, {myFuncs, Level[expr,1]}]
expr
```

> ```
> y[f[u],g[v],h[w]]
> ```

Otherwise, you could use the following function:

```
innerMap[fs_, expr_] := Head[expr] @@ MapThread[Construct, {fs, Level[expr,1]}] 
innerMap[myFuncs, expr]
```

> ```
> y[f[u],g[v],h[w]]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using an [`Iterator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-use-the-iterator-in-mathematica):

```
With[{fn = GeneralUtilities`ListIterator[{f, g, h}]},
 Unevaluated@Read[fn] /@ y[u, v, w]]

(*  y[f[u], g[v], h[w]]  *)
```

Comment: I have never seen `Iterator` before!  It's quite old, too.

Comment: @QuantumDot It can be convenient, but it hasn't got a lot of exposure. There are hints in the comments that something better might be on its way, but it's been a while.  Note that for performance-intensive operations, `Table`, `Do`-loops, and `Map`-ping over packed arrays are much more efficient.