# Implementing Newton's Method?

Tags: equation-solving, procedural-programming

For an assignment, I have to implement Newton's method using
`Module` and a `For` loop. So far, I have

```
newtMethod[guess_, fun_] :=
 ( Module[{k, x0, x1},
   x0 = guess;
   For[k = 1,
    Abs[x1 - x0] >= .0001,
    k = k + 1,
    x1 = (x0 - fun[x0]/fun'[x0]);
    If[Abs[x1 - x0] < 0, x0 = x1, x1 = x1];
    x1]; Print[x1]])
```

When I run this, a strange message appears.

```
f[x_] := Sin[E^x];
newtMethod[2.5, f]
x1$5709
```

If I remove the
`Print[x1]`
part of the code, there's NO output entirely. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any meaning to the weird output? I think my error has to do with what I included in the
`For` loop and what I defined `x1` to be, but I'm not sure. Any tips?

Comment: `Nest`, `NestWhile` or `FixedPoint` should be better choices.

Comment: Also you don't need the `Print` at all. Mathematica expressions like `Module`/`Block` return their final result, so you'll get `x1` from that, no printing necessary

Answer (score 8):

The main reason is that `x1` is not assigned a value before entering the for loop:

```
newtMethod[guess_, 
  fun_] := (Module[{k, x0, x1}, x0 = guess; 
   x1 = (x0 - fun[x0]/fun'[x0]);
   For[k = 1, Abs[x1 - x0] < .0001, k = k + 1, 
    x1 = (x0 - fun[x0]/fun'[x0]);
    If[Abs[x1 - x0] < 0, x0 = x1, x1 = x1];
    x1]; Print[x1]])

f[x_] := Sin[E^x];
newtMethod[2.5, f]
FindRoot[Sin[E^x] == 0, {x, 2.5}]
```

Answer (score 8):

Worth putting it out there that the `For` loop is not your friend. This does the same

```
newtonOneLine // Clear
newtonOneLine[fun_, x0_, tol_ : .0001, maxIters_ : 1000] :=
 
 Module[{fp = fun'},
  FixedPoint[# - (fun[#]/fp[#]) &, 
   x0, 
   SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < tol &)
   ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, since interest in Newton's method never seems to fade on this site, here's a `Iterator[]` based approach:

```
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`";

(*
 * fixedPointIterator
 *   Returns x = f[x] unless x == f[x]
 *)
ClearAll[fixedPointIterator];
fixedPointIterator[f_, x0_, sameQ_ : SameQ] := 
 GeneralUtilities`NewIterator[
  fixedPointIterator,  (* name *)
  {x = x0},            (* state variables *)
  With[{xx = f[x]},    (* iterator action *)
   If[sameQ[x, xx],
    GeneralUtilities`IteratorExhausted,
    x = xx]]
  ]

newtonIterator[f_, x0_, sameQ_ : Equal] :=
 fixedPointIterator[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0, sameQ]

ff[x_] := Sin[E^x];
rootIt = newtonIterator[ff, 2.5];

ReadList[rootIt, 100 (* max iterations *)]
ff[%] (* check *)
```

> ```
> (*
>   {2.53316, 2.53103, 2.53102, 2.53102}
>   {0.0268055, 0.0000221047, 1.94364*10^-11, -4.89859*10^-16}
> *)
> ```

Note: `Equal` compares real numbers with tolerance (equal up to their last seven bits). `SameQ` compares real numbers with smaller tolerance (equal up to their last bit).  Pass a custom comparator to use a different tolerance.

Also, the overhead of `Iterator[]` makes it fairly slow compared to, say, `FixedPoint[]`.

Comment: Never heard of this!  Looks like https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-use-the-iterator-in-mathematica is a good source for more info if anyone else is curious.

Comment: Iterator can, it seems, be used in compiled stuff too, which might be a useful way to go with this

Comment: @b3m2a1 `Compile` or `FunctionCompile`? I can't get it to work with either one. I'm not very good at `FunctionCompile`, tho.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ah looks like I just got confused by the existence of ``Compile`SetIterate`` and ``Compile`IteratorCount`` in ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort``

Answer (score 5):

First, let me just cleaning up the orignal code and the answer from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/234969/148:

```
newtMethod[guess_, fun_] := 
  Module[{k, x0 = guess, x1},
  x1 = x0 - fun[x0]/fun'[x0];
  For[k = 1, Abs[x1 - x0] < .0001, k++, 
   x1 = x0 - fun[x0]/fun'[x0];
   If[Abs[x1 - x0] < 0, x0 = x1, x1 = x1]];
  x1]
```

This returns the most recent value of `x1` rather than printing it; initializes `x0` within the first argument to `Module`; and elides superfluous parentheses.

*Note 1:* For serious work, you'd want to use a fixed limit on the number of steps, either through hard-coding into the body of `newtMethod` or as an additional, argument to `newtMethod`. (For that matter, it would be more generally useful to make the tolerance `.0001` another argument to `newtMethod`.)

*Note 2:* It is *dangerous* to use as stopping criterion just closeness of successive x-values to each other, and essential for some functions &meash; those that are fairly flat — to use in addition closeness of the value of `f` at the current x to the desired value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all sure what is going on here.

1. The For loop test seems backwards. In the test example the logic test is initially not true so the loop isn't executed.
2. In the If statement the test for Abs[anything]<0 doesn't seem to make sense?