# Selecting 1st $n$ elements meeting criterion from very long list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need to select `n` elements from a list, which satisfy a condition. I need something like

```
Take[Select[r, (Length[FactorInteger[#]] > 100)&], 500]
```

but `r` might be something like `Range[10^10]`, and I don't want `Select` to range over `10^10` elements when I need only first 500.

Comment: `Cases` has a number restriction: `Cases[r, x_ /; Length[FactorInteger[x]] > 100, 1, 500]`. But remember that if the length of `Select[r, ...]` is a problem, then surely the length of `r` itself must be an even bigger problem, right?

Comment: Are you [aware](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) that Select has an optional final argument that specifies the max number of items to return, and early terminates when it reaches that limit?  E.g. `Select[Range[500],#<600&,200]===Range[200]` $\mapsto$ `True` . Perhaps you're asking for a way to pass a lazy-evaluating list to a select type operation?

Comment: Yes, "lazy-evaluating list" is that interests me. It's strange that I missed this moment in the Help.

Comment: If you really want a lazy list w/ a filter, consider the beautiful functional approach by WReach [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/885/51526) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func [r_, l_] := Module[{i = 0},


  Reap[Scan[If[Length@FactorInteger[#]  > 100 && i < l, Sow[#]; i = i + 1] &, r]][[2]]



  ]
```

Comment: If enough results are accumulated fast enough, it might be faster to use a `While` loop. If it needs to go through the entire list, though, `Scan` is faster. All depends on how the elements you want are distributed.

Comment: @aardvark2012  thanks, I didn't know it